# How to get the information of a specific process given its process ID using the command 'ps' in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, process, sh, ps

How to get the information of a specific process given its process ID using the command 'ps' in Linux. I also want to get the proportion of memory the process occupies.

Is that '`ps processID`' ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
  pmap $PID
```

or perhaps

```
  cat /proc/$PID/maps
```

and/or

```
  cat /proc/$PID/status
```

See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

`ps -o pmem h -p processID`

`pmem`: Ratio of the process's resident set size to the physical memory on the machine, expressed as a percentage.